# Azure linux VM (RHEL) disk not attaching giving error disk01' of size '256' GB is invalid

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting issues while creating the linux VM using terraform code, below is the error:

> creating/updating Managed Disk "test-usrtest-disk01" (Resource Group
> "rg-eu1-test"): compute.DisksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
> request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest"
> Message="MaxShares '0' for disk 'test-usrtest-disk01' of size '256' GB
> is invalid. Please refer to
> [https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-shared-enable#disk-sizes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-shared-enable#disk-sizes%22)

The interesting thing is, from the Azure portal I am able to attach the disk. but using terraform code is not working but the same code works for other environments.

**Input**

```
"disks": [
                    {
                        "name": "usrtest-disk",
                        "disk_size": 256,
                        "number_of_disks": 1,
                        "storage_account_type": "Premium_LRS",
                        "write_accelerator_enabled": false,
                        "caching": "ReadWrite"
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Hello, could you please share your terraform code?

Comment: Updated in the post. let me know If you have any specific things to check. As I mentioned same code working for other envrionments.

Comment: Could you please try to add option `"max_shares": 1` in your terraform code?

Comment: If I will add this option my disk will be shared right? which I don't want.

Comment: Microsoft article says - Q: If I no longer want to use a disk in shared mode, how do I disable it? A: Unmount the disk from all VMs that it is attached to. Then change the maxShare property on the disk to 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared#frequently-asked-questions

Comment: If you add option `"max_shares": 1` in your terraform code - disk in shared mode will be disabled

Comment: @AndriyBilous , Thanks for your help, I will try and confirm here!

Comment: @AndriyBilous The true issue with Terraform version... the earlier version was 1.0.03, and I had not specified any version in the Azure rm, so it was the most recent one. However, it appears to be throwing an error. So I went back to the previous version, removed the.terraform folder and statefiles, and upgraded the latest version 1.0.08 and tried again. So far, it appears to be in good functioning order.

Comment: Hello @SudhirGoswami, can you please post the above changes that you did  to an answer below . so that it will be benificial for other community members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by **Sudhir Goswami** , The main issue was with `Terraform version` which is why there was a conflict in bad request . Downgrading to previous version and then upgrading it to the recent version by completely cleaning up the terraform and state files solved the issue.

Thank You [@SudhirGoswami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6653070/sudhir-goswami) , for providing the steps in the comments section.